# Remmina: how to restore window title bar?

Tags: remmina

Remmina 1.4.25
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
Qt Version: 5.15.3

I changed a setting in Remmina and now there's no title bar or "More Actions" icon in the upper left hand corner of the remote connection window. I can't grab the remote window and move it around anymore, and I can't find any setting that gives me the window chrome back.

How do I restore window features on the remote window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop your scale to 100% under *System Settings > Display and Monitor > Display Configuration*

Remmina being GTK and trying to size to your client resolution perfectly crops out the window decorations at the default 125% scaling of a lot of laptops.

Answer (score 2):

You have clicked on the **Toggle fullscreen mode** button.

Press <kbd>Right_Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (i.e., while holding pressed the **Right** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on the keyboard, press the <kbd>F</kbd> key), to restore the window to normal mode.

You can also move your mouse to middle top of your screen to reveal the additional actions that normally you see on the left of the remote connection window.

Comment: I am familiar with "Toggle Fullscreen". Alas, no. I have the tabs for open sessions across the top, but no title bar and no window menu icon in the upper left as with other apps.